# How to initialise jquery Keyframes

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to use [jquery Keyframes](https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes) for dynamically created keyframe animations. I have six icons on my page (could be more) which all need to be animated to random `x` and `y` values between the following ranges:

`x = 1-5`
`y = 13-20`

The animation should allow the icon to move/hover/bob around with the values randomly selected using the above range.

I am using jQuery keyframes which describes itself as:

> allow[ing] dynamic generation of CSS3 keyframes with callback events

Firstly I am randomly generating `x` and `y`

```
var x = randomInt(5, 1); // use this value for x in translate3d
var y = randomInt(20, 13); // use this value for y in translate3d
```

Works fine.

Then I am creating the keyframe using the syntax found in the documentation, including my `x` and `y` values:

```
$.keyframe.define([{
   name: 'gentleHover',
   '0%': {'tranform': 'translate3D(0px,0px,0px)'},
   '50%': {'tranform': 'translate3D('+x+'px,'+y+'px,0px)'},
   '100%': {'tranform': 'translate3D(0px,0px,0px)'}
}]);
```

And then I am calling the animation to play:

```
$('#'+iconID+' img').playKeyframe(
    'gentleHover 1s linear infinite'
);
```

Not getting any errors, variables are all correct as expected but **nothing happens** IRT to the animation. I can see the animation is being applied to the icon:

```
<img src="http://digitalshowcase.somethingbigdev.co.uk/assets/cats/4.png" class="boostKeyframe" style="animation-play-state: initial; -webkit-animation-play-state: initial; animation-duration: 1s; -webkit-animation: gentleHover 1s linear infinite; animation-timing-function: linear; animation-delay: initial; animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-direction: initial; animation-fill-mode: initial; animation-name: gentleHover;">
```

I can also see the keyframe being created but I can't get it to play it?

Here is a live link including all of the above:

http://digitalshowcase.somethingbigdev.co.uk/cats-test.html

#### Edit:

I have just tested with the code generated via the jQuery and have discovered the generated code doesn't actually work to animate, so perhaps this is the issue. But I cannot see what is wrong with the generated code as it all looks OK to me?: https://jsfiddle.net/h359tt4L/

Comment: Have you tried `$.keyframe.debug = true;`? Maybe it will show what the problem is. I don't see important difference between your code and the one from docs, so it is supposed to work.

Comment: @Regent I have. The debug shows "style applied" and "rendered style" with exactly what I'd expect. But no animation plays.

Comment: By the way, is `$.keyframe.define` inside `document.ready` (or `window.load`)?

Comment: @Regent currently document.ready. Just tried window.load - no difference.

Comment: SOLVED. Transform spelt incorrectly.

Comment: Indeed it is ;) It was correct in your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example "transform" is spelt incorrectly. After fixing that, it worked for me in chrome.

You can also follow the spec a little bit closer by changing...

`transform:translate3D(0px, 0px, 0px);`

to

`transform:translate3D(0, 0, 0);`